# What is 'lastfm' protocol URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, fetch, last.fm

For example, [Playlists API](https://www.last.fm/api/playlists):

> Use the playlist.fetch method call to fetch XSPF playlists. XSPF is a
> web standard for sharable playlists, and XSPF libraries are available
> in several languages. playlist.fetch takes a 'lastfm' protocol URL as
> an argument; this identifies the playlist you're requesting. The
> following protocol url schemes are currently supported:

```
Album Playlists: lastfm://playlist/album/<album_id>
User Playlists: lastfm://playlist/<playlist_id>
Tag Playlists: lastfm://playlist/tag/<tag_name>/freetracks
```

How to send request with `playlist.fetch`? I can't understand what is 'lastfm' protocol? How to use it?

Example playlist:

```
https://www.last.fm/ru/user/RJ/playlists/2615079
```

Comment: Your examples *show you the protocol*, as well as describing it: `lastfm:`. In your case the URL would be `"lastfm://playlist/2615079"`

Comment: @jonrsharpe and what do with it?

Comment: What do you mean? Pass it to playlist.fetch, presumably.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how to pass this param `lastfm://playlist/2615079`? For example, 404 error: `fetch('https://www.last.fm/api/show/playlist.fetch?' + 'lastfm://playlist/2615079')`

Comment: I don't know, I assumed playlist.fetch was a *method* not part of a URL. Maybe look elsewhere in the API docs to see how to structure the requests.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this url `https://www.last.fm/api/show/playlist.fetch` shows after click  `playlist.fetch method`. Other way `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=playlist.fetch&user=rj&api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&format=json` - error `No method with that name in this package`.

Comment: The Playlists API is now deprecated, cf. https://www.last.fm/api/playlists